# how to display full string value of variable in VS2005 watch window?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

Looks like the variable's value displayed in watch windows of VS2005 is truncated. Only about 255? bytes is shown. Can we config VS2005 to show the full lengh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the whole string if you click on the text visualizer (magnifying glass next to the value)